# Get cell value when column is collapsed in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know how to get specific cell value from datagid:

```
  TextBlock cellValue = myDataGrid.Columns[colIndex].GetCellContent(myDataGrid.Items[rowindex]) as TextBlock;
```

But let's say I collaped my last column like:

```
<Page x:Class="Lib.MyApp"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      ...
      Loaded="OnLoad"> 


public MyApp()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   myDataGrid.Columns[myDataGrid.Columns.Count - 1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

How to get cell value when the wanted column is collapsed? I mean when the column is visibale I can get the wanted cell value like `cellValue.Value` but when the column is collapsed I get that `cellValue` is `null`

Comment: This is a good example of why you should separate your U.I. from your data ... ItemList[itemIndex].SomeProperty is always available.

Comment: I agree with Peregrine. Not via the ui is the answer.  Working with UI like this is what you do in other technologies but it's the hard way to do things in wpf. Bind an observablecollection<t> to the itemssource of the datagrid. Work with the data in that. It's common for that t to be a viewmodel which contains logic rather than a model instance directly matches a row of data in your database ( or wherever the data comes from ).